# Forward/proxy POST request but always serve static file

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

What I would like to do is forward/proxy/fcgi a request (POST) to an external process/server but have the response come directly from Apache serving a static file. The response of the external process to Apache would be ignored/irrelevant and the response code to the client would always be success.

```
 --------   req   --------  proxy ----------
|        | --->  |        | ---> | external |  #Ignore response 
|        |       |        |       ----------
| Client |       | Apache |
|        |  res  |        |       -------------
|        | <---  |        | <--- | Static file | #Always serve this
 --------         --------        -------------
```

Is this possible with 'stock' Apache 2.2/2.4?  What set of directives/modules do I need to investigate?

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Sounds like it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222815/mod-rewrite-only-on-get

Comment: @wurtel that question look like it about request method, not really what  I'm asking. I want my reversed proxied service to get the request from the client, but the client gets served a static file via apache, regardless of what my proxied service responds with.

Comment: no, you can not substitude the response from a bakend to an arbitrary response of yours by standard means, I guess at the very least you will need some kind of script or programming to do. Perhaps the most sane thing is change to backend to give the appropiate response you need.